# Set a variable from ng-view

Tags: javascript, templates, angularjs

I am trying to learn AngularJS and I came across a problem where I have difficulties to solve it.

I have small application based on this template.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="fff">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <head>

  <body class="{{bodyClass}}"> 
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="/static/js/all.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would like to change `bodyClass` in `ng-view`. What is the best practice solution such a case?

Comment: Use ng-class directive. I think that would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this using route change by putting controller there

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(ev,data) {   
     if (data.$route && data.$route.controller)
       $rootScope.controller = data.$route.controller;
   })
});
```

and change `<body class="{{bodyClass}}">`  to  `<body ng-class="controller">`

Check http://plnkr.co/edit/fR6gSqeXbROl410tgzPJ?p=preview

Comment: How can I change a variable in template?

Comment: Do you want to change this {{bodyClass}} with a value in your app or you want to change bodyClass from {{bodyClass}}?

Comment: I would like to change bodyClass inside ng-view template. for login page I need login-page class, for register page I need register-page style.

Answer (score 0):

The variable used in your body must come from some controller. Inside ng-view you will most likely also have a page with a controller. This controller is now a child of the 'body' controller. This means that you can access parent variables from your 'child' controller.

Please read this: [Scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes). The is a very, very good read about scopes. I even think this is a must read.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to take object and define the bodyClass over it. Something like

`$scope.appStyles={bodyClass:'default'}`

This property should be defined over a controller defined on parent of `ng-view` html.

Now you would get this `appStyle` object in all `ng-view` scope,as they inherit the parent $scope. Which also means you can change it anywhere like

`$scope.appStyles.bodyClass='newClass';`

A better approach would be to move these settings into a service and share.